# How to update the calendar when an item is updated in the list using SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, update, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a calendar of SharePoint list and it creates events through the forms. SharePoint Designer 2013 is the one doing all this process in a workflow. However, when an item is submitted it creates events in the calendar but when somebody goes again and changes the date/ time it doesn't get updated in the calendar. I am trying to figure out how could I do this and also if there is a possibility to store the change date / times or previous ones as well. That will be great then.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a another sample workflow to update the calendar item based on changes in the custom list column, before updating check if the current value of your custom list not equal to value in the calendar list column. Something like below :

```
If column 1  value in calendar list - ne column 1 value in the custom list 

Then

Update Item column 1 in the calendar list =Value from a custom list.
```

**Or**

Trigger the same workflow with the above logic on the item modification event.

**Updated Answer (Details implementation)**:

**Workflow Details:**

Update item in another list using the SharePoint designer workflow.

[image: Copy-List-Item-To-Another-List-Using-Designer-Workflow-Calendar-List-workflow-demo]

**Workflow Explanation**

In the if condition I am checking the value of “Title” column in the calendar list where I have set the hardcoded “Test1” value – this is to match the target item i.e. calendar list before updating from the custom list which item the workflow should update – here I am just checking if the “Title” column has the value of “Test1” – when the workflow runs on the custom list, it will update the calendar list item where Title equals to “Test1”

[image: Define-Update-Lookup-update-item-SharePoint-Desinger-workflow-2]

**Notes**:

Ideally, in real-time to make this complete automated, we should have a common column in both the custom list and target list (here, calendar list) so that we can dynamically check the condition before updating the target list, here in the above demo just updating by checking the hardcoded value for the “Title” in the calendar list for the proof of concept.

Now click on the update item configuration.

In the top as mentioned below, select the target list, here it is a calendar list.

Then select each column from the calendar list which you want to update and in the value header set the corresponding column from the source list that is a custom list by clicking on the “Add” button.

And in the “Find the List Item” section “Title” from the calendar list and value as “Test1“. That’s it, done!!!

[image: Update-List-Item-configuration-in-SharePoint-designer-workflow-1]

For more details refer to the below article:

[How to a copy list item to another list using SharePoint designer workflow](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/how-to-a-copy-list-item-to-another-list-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Comment: Hi thanks. I have added a picture of how my workflow works. Can you please see that and advise how can I ammend it then. Cheers

Comment: And also I never made a custom List can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Good no issues -  there are various types of lists in SharePoint, custom list and calendar is different types of that. I think in your requirement you have two lists i.e custom list and calendar list... once user creates item in custom list, you are adding some entries to the calendar list as an item... Aso I believe you are running the workflow in the custom list. I think for the better maintability you should create a separate new workflow which should only trigger on item modification, then implement the above logic. your first wf should trigger on item creation n this one on modification.

Comment: Hi, This makes absolutely perfect sense, thank you for explaining. The only I'm facing is in the set field thing in the fields it is just showing the values of the custom list but not the calendar list that's why I am not able to select the calendar list item. I have added a photo as well. Please have a look.

Comment: Please refer this example - how to do https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/16a21f00-bb22-4d7a-b2fd-92eee3254391/update-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2013

Comment: Hi @Habib. I have seen that example and again the same thing happens that empty doesn't appear with the date / time columns as in the example they are doing it with the Title field. 
Stuck here.

Comment: Ohh is it -  I will check and update it here

Comment: Ok mate thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Noman: Sorry for the late, I have updated my answer and implemented it in details. :-)